# Rails and ajax - passing values to partial view

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.2.3

I need to insert many rows for a table by clicking a link using AJAX. It's working perfect but there is an issue. When I pass the value `@paged_photo`  to partial it's null there. However it's definitely not null, it contains a data.

**#home/index.html.erb**

```
<table   id="photos_table">
  <%= render :partial => 'test_partial'  %>
</table>
  <%= link_to "More photos",  {:controller => "home", :action => "test_method" }, :remote => true %>
```

**#home/_test_partial.html.erb**;
 **#there are 3 td for each row**
 **#@paged_photos is null here for some reason**

```
<tr>
<td>
   <%= link_to :controller => 'photos', :action => 'show', :id=>@paged_photos[0].id do %>
       <%=image_tag(@paged_photos[0].source)%>
   <%end%>
</td>
<td>
   <%= link_to :controller => 'photos', :action => 'show', :id=>@paged_photos[1].source do %>
       <%=image_tag(@paged_photos[1].source)%>
   <%end%>
</td>
<td>
   <%= link_to :controller => 'photos', :action => 'show', :id=>@paged_photos[2].id do %>
       <%=image_tag(@paged_photos[2].source)%>
   <%end%>
</td>
</tr>
```

**#home/test_method.js.erb**

```
$('#photos_table').append('# <%=j render :partial => 'test_partial'%>');
```

**controller**

```
   def test_method
        @paged_photos = get_photos        
        respond_to() do |format|
          format.js
        end
     end
```

How do I pass the value to partial to insert a row for a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use the following in your `home/test_method.js.erb`?

```
$('#photos_table').append('<%=j render :partial => 'test_partial', :paged_photos => @paged_photos %>');
```

After this, access `paged_photos` in `home/_test_partial.html.erb`.

If that works, you'll have to modify your `home/index.html.erb` like this

```
<%= render :partial => 'test_partial', :paged_photos => @paged_photos %>
```

PS : I didn't understand the use of `#` before `<%=j` in `home/test_method.js.erb`. Was it just a typo or it's intentional?

Comment: And how I access it within partial? `<%=:paged_photos%>` isn't working.

Comment: Actually, it's not necessary to do what you wrote. I just can define a variable @my_var within controller method and access it within partial

Comment: @AlexMaslakov you can simply access `paged_photos` variable in your views. Example `<%= paged_photos %>`. You are right about `@my_var` part but I have a doubt whether it's being passed on while rendering via Ajax.

Comment: it throws an exception <%=paged_photos%> because it is not defined.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov Are you sure you modified `index.html.erb` as I have suggested in my answer? See second code snippet.